Calculating distance between two trains
Two trains A &  B of length 400m each are moving on two parallel tracks with a uniform speed of 20ms-1 in the same direction, with A ahead of B. The driver of B decides to overtake A and accelerates by 1ms-2. If after 50s, the guard of B just brushes past the driver of A what was the original distance between them?
I tried solving it as follows: Let the original distance between the trains be x. When the guard of B brushes driver of A, train B would have travelled 400+x m.
We have the values for u, a, t and s.
Using s=ut+1/2at2 we get x=1850m.
But the actual answer is 1250m and upon searching the solution online, I find that to calculate x, the distance travelled by both the trains in the given time has been subtracted.
What is wrong with this method?

You should leave the units out of the equation. You have $400+x $m, followed by $x=1850$m, which, when placed back in the equation you get: $400 + 0.185$ hectare, which is number plus an area: not good, and neither are a length.

I hope you're familiar with the concept of relative motion. Relative to the train ahead, the train behind has only the acceleration of $1ms^{-2}$, and no initial velocity. Or you could do it separately (what you did), but then don't forget to factor in the front train also moving.

@JEB, he obviously meant $(400+x)m$

@Ekarshi Thank you

@Ekarshi it's not obvious to me. Anyway, if so: then $x$ is dimensionless, and is not equal to be measure in meters. It's better to use $L, x$, and set $L=400,$m at the end. If you insist on using numbers, then declare "all values are in coherent S.I. units" and check the dimensions at the end--that is unambiguous.

Well, yes there is one main problem. The distance travelled by B only
$400+x$ and not $x$.
Therefore,
$$S=ut+{\frac 1 2 }at^2$$
By, using relative motion concept,
$u=0 m/s$ and $a=1 m/s^2$
$$x={\frac 1 2 } × 1 × 50 × 50$$
$$x=1250 m$$
I hope that helps you.
